# An attempt to define expected value of a Riemannian manifold valued random variable - what'll go wrong?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, pr.probability, riemannian-geometry, probability-distributions, geometric-probability

Let $X:\Omega\to (M,g)$ be a random variable taking values in a Riemannian manifold $(M,g)$ with the Riemannian volume form denoted by $dvol_g(x).$ We know that there's no standard way to generalize the expected value or mean of $X$ on $M,$ and the standard generalization used in the literature is the Fréchet mean, which, if exist(s) is/are the minimizer of the variance function $p\mapsto d_g(X,p)^2$ of $X.$

$$E[X]= arg min_{p\in M} E[d_g(X,p)^2]$$

In case of discrete data $\{x_1\dots x_n\}\subset M,$ this becomes

$$\bar{x}:=  arg min_{p\in M} \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}d_g(x_i,p)^2$$

We know that Fréchet mean doesn't always exist and even if it does, may not be unique. I'm sure there's no way to remedy this, but I was still thinking of the following approach:

We do understand that the expressions $\int_{M}xf_X(x)dvol_g(x)$ (in case $X$ is continuous, so its density $f_X(x)$ exists) or the $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i$ doesn't make sense. But what'd go wrong if we try to isometrically embed $\Phi:(M,g)\to \mathbb{R}^D$ using the Nash embedding and attempt to define $E[X]$ by:

$$E[X]:=\Phi^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\Phi(x_i)\right)$$

in the discrete case, and by

$$E[X]:= \Phi^{-1}\left(\int_{M}\Phi(x)f_X(x)dvol_g(x)\right)$$

in the continuous case?

Of course, we know that $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\Phi(x_i)\in \mathbb{R}^D$ or $\int_{M}\Phi(x)f_X(x)dvol_g(x)\in \mathbb{R}^D$ does not necessarily belong to the image of the Nash embedding map $\Phi,$ so the $ \Phi^{-1}$ above doesn't necessarily make sense.  But it's so natural to think of this approach, that I wonder if there's a class of Riemannian manifolds where these above quantities will (i) indeed lie in the image of $\Phi,$ and if yes, (ii) the attempted definition of $E[X]$ will be independent of the chosen embedding $\Phi?$ I'd highly appreciate being pointed to the right literature.

Comment: It will almost never be the case that the $\Phi$-image $\Phi(M)$ of $M$ is convex. So, generally, the mean of a distribution on $\Phi(M)$ will not be in $\Phi(M)$. So, I don't see how this could work.

Comment: did you have some specific goal in mind that you wanted to try to formulate mean/variance for? Maybe we can help with that original goal instead.

Comment: The first step to clarify the situation should consist in passing from "manifold-valued random variables" to their distributions, i.e., to probability measures on the manifold.

Comment: @IosifPinelis Yes unfortunately, I see that, it's not even true for visualizable examples like $S^n\subset \mathbb{R}^{n+1}.$

Comment: @ThomasKojar Not really, I keep track of (at east part of) the literature of manifold valued random variables. I guess I'm just unhappy that the Fréchet mean, defined in the OP and used in this literature, is not unique, and I'd have been happy of it was, hence that unsuccessful effort!

Well somewhat generally, mean of manifold-valued random variables is a well-studied subject in medical imaging community and the definition of Fréchet mean that I wrote above is also common in the community, although it doesn't usually consist of probabilists.